# Passing quoted arguments to PowerShell scripts

Tags: powershell, parameters, quotes

Scripting is made for CLI and, in the Microsoft world, script arguments referring to files may often have spaces requiring them to be quoted.

This turns out to be problematic for me. Consider this script:

```
#testarg.ps1 
for($i=0; $i -lt $args.length; $i++)
{
    write-host "Arg$i = $($args[$i])"
}
```

If I run it inside the PowerShell interactive environment, like this:

```
PS C:\script> .\testarg.ps1 "first arg"  "second arg"
```

I get, as expected,

```
Arg0 = first arg
Arg1 = second arg
```

But the ordinary use of a script would be, outside the interactive mode, in a batch one. As far as I understand, [the Microsoft suggested way](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/374e2db5-89cf-4217-85e6-ca0014271059) to run scripts from `cmd.exe` seems to be `powershell.exe path\to\script.ps1` (without space in path). But:

```
powershell.exe .\testarg.ps1 "first arg"  "second arg"
```

gives the inconsistent result:

```
Arg0 = first
Arg1 = arg
Arg2 = second
Arg3 = arg
```

I noted that to obtain the intended result I can use single quotes:

```
powershell.exe .\testarg.ps1 'first arg' 'second arg'
```

But this is often not viable when the script is to be run by GUI tools that automatically generate and pass the arguments, and/or in presence of more CLI tools for reason of consistency in the use of the quotes.

For some reason when using the `-file` option:

```
powershell.exe –file .\testarg.ps1 "first arg"  "second arg"
::(reference to relative path '.\' is optional)
```

I get again the intended result:

```
Arg0 = first arg
Arg1 = second arg
```

So with the `-file` option the double quotes work properly. This suggests that one can remap the Windows file type association for `ps1` files (with `FTYPE.exe`) to something like:

```
FTYPE Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -file "%1" %*
```

Given the FTYPE association, I can obtain the intended result by simply writing:

```
testarg.ps1 "first arg"  "second arg"
```

The latter is quite satisfying for me, but since I am newbie with PowerShell, I wonder:

1. For a general script, are the batch form `powershell.exe –file path\to\script.ps1` and the interactive form (from within PowerShell) `PS > path\to\script.ps1` equivalent? Are there some instances when the two forms may produce different output/effects?
2. Is there a possible solution inside the script to read the command line as is (without stripping double quotes)? Something like `*%` for `cmd.exe`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one thing I don't understand when you wrote:

```
testarg.ps1 "first arg"  "second arg"
```

Inside which batch are you calling that?

From `PowerShell.exe`, it should be written:

```
cd "c:\Temp"
& .\testarg.ps1 "first arg"  "second arg"
```

From `cmd.exe` it should be written:

```
powershell –file .\testarg.ps1 "first arg" "second arg"
```

Comment: It was intended from within `cmd.exe` after associating `Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1` type to PowerShellScript.exe. Anyway I rewrote my original question to make it clearer.

Comment: From the command prompt, `powershell -f testarg.ps1 "first arg" "second arg"` is the way to go. FYI, however, `powershell .\testarg.ps1 """first arg""" """second arg"""` happens to also yield the same results; this will not help with your file type association, though…